# jqxwidgets date value displays date 1970

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqxwidgets

I am trying to display date value from mysql database, it displays value successfully but its displaying date "Saturday, January 17, 1970 7:27 PM"

[image]

I am using following code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // prepare the data

            var theme = 'energyblue';
            var source =
            {
                 datatype: "json",
                 datafields: [
                     { name: 'startdate', type: 'date'},
                     { name: 'scheduleend', type: 'date'},
                     { name: 'venue', type: 'string'},
                     { name: 'trainer', type: 'string'},
                     { name: 'course', type: 'string'},
                     { name: 'link', type: 'string'}

                ],
                url: 'data.php',
                cache: false,
                filter: function()
                {
                    // update the grid and send a request to the server.
                    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter');
                },
                sort: function()
                {
                    // update the grid and send a request to the server.
                    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'sort');
                },
                root: 'Rows',
                beforeprocessing: function(data)
                {       
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        source.totalrecords = data[0].TotalRows;                    
                    }
                }
            };      
            var dataadapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
                    loadError: function(xhr, status, error)
                    {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                }
            );

            // initialize jqxGrid
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {       
                source: dataadapter,
                theme: theme,
                width: 1220,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                autoheight: true,
                pageable: true,
                virtualmode: true,
                localization: getLocalization('en'),
                rendergridrows: function(obj)
                {
                     return obj.data;    
                },
                columns: [
                     { text: 'Start Date', datafield: 'startdate', width: 260, cellsformat: 'f' },
                     { text: 'End Date', datafield: 'scheduleend', width: 260, cellsformat: 'f'},
                     { text: 'Venue', datafield: 'venue', width: 120 },
                     { text: 'Trainer', datafield: 'trainer', width: 150 },
                     { text: 'Course', datafield: 'course', width: 350 },
                    { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 80, cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', cellsformat: 'c2', cellsrenderer: function(row, cell, value) {
            return '<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;"><a href="'+value+'"/>View</a></div>'
} }
                  ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Why date is displayed "Saturday, January 17, 1970 7:27 PM" ? How to display original date value?

Any reference or help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: try adding `columntype` property to start and end date column

Comment: still same result 1970.

Comment: There must be some error in your databse json datafield data format . Can you put your code in any fiddle or can you paste some json data sample ?